# How to fail build on low test coverage with activator / sbt?

Tags: java, sbt, code-coverage, playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

I'm working on a pure Java project with playframework 2.3 and using Jacoco4sbt as code coverage tool.
What should I do in order to get the build fail when code coverage is below a threshold ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your project's `build.sbt` file just add the following

```
jacoco.settings ++ Seq(           
  jacoco.thresholds in jacoco.Config := Thresholds(  
  instruction = 90,   
  method = 90,  
  branch = 90,  
  complexity = 90,  
  line = 90,  
  clazz = 90)  
  )
```

And run at your project's root `activator jacoco:cover dist`

Comment: It says `error: not found: value Thresholds`. Is there an extra import necessary or something?

Comment: Needed `import de.johoop.jacoco4sbt.Thresholds`.